# Set up ssh client to disconnect after inactivity

Tags: ssh

I'd like to configure my ssh client to disconnect from a particular host after some period of inactivity. I do not have root access to the server.  I need to do this from the client, not the server; the user on the server is shared among multiple people.

Ideally I could do this via my ssh config file so that I can source control the file and carry it to my many home directories.

I've tried the following entry in my ssh config file (~/.ssh/config):

```
Host somehostname
    Hostname somehostname
    User someuser
    ConnectTimeout 60
```

However after I log in and wait > 60 seconds I am still connected.

I'm using:

```
$ ssh -v
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
```

Comment: I see there is some ambiguity regarding the definition of "inactivity".  Could you define more clearly what you mean by "some period of inactivity"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the man page for `ssh_config` says, `ConnectTimeout`

> Specifies the timeout (in seconds) used when connecting to the SSH
>   server, instead of using the default system TCP timeout.  This
>                value is used only when the target is down or really unreachable, not when it refuses the connection.

It is **not** the equivalent of e.g. bash's `$TMOUT` variable, that is, autologout from the shell when the interactive session is idle.  I don't think you can do what you want, in the way you want to do it (ie, client-side).

Comment: Garrett, I'm glad we found a workaround that worked for you.  If I may presume, local etiquette is that when you're satisfied with an answer to your question you accept it by clicking the tick outline next to it, which drives the SF reputation system for both questioner and answerer.  My apologies if you already know that.

Answer (score 0):

Several factors are in play here:

- the sshd server's `CLientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax` settings determine how long the client may remain unresponsive before being disconnected.
- the client's `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` settings determine how long the server may remain unresponsive before the client will disconnect.

You could alter the Server*-related settings for your client, but that would not override the Client* settings on the server, and since both client and server will send a keepAlive message to each other at the set intervals, you'd have to change the setting on the server as well.